# Spark UDF optimization for Graph Database (Neo4j) inserts

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, parallel-processing, data-ingestion

This is first issue i am posting so apologies if i miss some info and mediocre formatting. I can update if required.

I will try to add as many details as possible. I have a not so optimized Spark Job which converts RDBMS data to graph nodes and relations in Neo4j.

To do this. Here is the steps i follow:

1. create a denormalized dataframe 'data' with spark sql and joins.
2. Foreach row in 'data' run a graphInsert function which does the following:

   a. read contents of the row  
     b. formulate a neo4j cypher query (We use [Merge](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/07/31/cypher-merge-explained.html) command so that we have have only one City e.g. Chicago created in Neo4j when Chicago will be present in multiple lines in RDBMS table)  
     c. connect to neo4j  
     d. execute the query  
     e. disconnect from neo4j

Here is the list of problems i am facing.

1. Inserts are slow.

> I know Merge query is slower than create but is there another way to do this instead of connecting and disconnecting for every record? This was my first draft code and maybe i am struggling how i will use one connection to insert from multiple threads on different  spark worker nodes. Hence connecting and disconnecting for every record.

2. The job is not scalable. It only runs fine with 1 core. As soon as i run the job with 2 spark cores i suddenly get 2 cities with same name, even when i am running merge queries. e.g. There are 2 Chicago cities which violates the use of Merge. I am assuming that Merge functions something like "Create if not exist".

> I dont know if my implementation is wrong in neo4j part or spark. If anyone can direct me to any documentation which helps me implement this on a better scale it will be helpful as i have a big spark cluster which i need to utilize at full potential for this job.

If you are interested to look at code instead of algorithm. Here is graphInsert implementation in scala:

```
class GraphInsert extends Serializable{
   var case_attributes = new Array[String](4)
   var city_attributes = new Array[String](2)
   var location_attributes = new Array[String](20)
   var incident_attributes = new Array[String](20)
   val prop = new Properties()
   prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/GraphInsertConnection.properties"))
   // properties Neo4j
   val url_neo4j = prop.getProperty("url_neo4j")
   val neo4j_user = prop.getProperty("neo4j_user")
   val neo4j_password = prop.getProperty("neo4j_password")


   def graphInsert(data : Row){  
      val query = "MERGE (d:CITY {name:city_attributes(0)})\n" +"MERGE (a:CASE { " + case_attributes(0)  + ":'" +data(11) + "'," +case_attributes(1)  + ":'" +data(13)  + "'," +case_attributes(2)  + ":'" +data(14) +"'}) \n" +"MERGE (b:INCIDENT { " + incident_attributes(0)  + ":" +data(0) + "," +incident_attributes(1)  + ":" +data(2)  + "," +incident_attributes(2)  + ":'" +data(3) +  "'," +incident_attributes(3)  + ":'" +data(8)+  "'," +incident_attributes(4)  + ":" +data(5) +  "," +incident_attributes(5)  + ":'" +data(4) +  "'," +incident_attributes(6)  + ":'" +data(6) +  "'," +incident_attributes(7)  + ":'" +data(1) +  "'," +incident_attributes(8)  + ":" +data(7)+"}) \n" +"MERGE (c:LOCATION { " + location_attributes(0)  + ":" +data(9) + "," +location_attributes(1)  + ":" +data(10)  + "," +location_attributes(2)  + ":'" +data(19) +  "'," +location_attributes(3)  + ":'" +data(20)+  "'," +location_attributes(4)  + ":" +data(18) +  "," +location_attributes(5)  + ":" +data(21) +  "," +location_attributes(6)  + ":'" +data(17) +  "'," +location_attributes(7)  + ":" +data(22) +  "," +location_attributes(8)  + ":" +data(23)+"}) \n" +"MERGE (a) - [r1:"+relation_case_incident+"]->(b)-[r2:"+relation_incident_location+"]->(c)-[r3:belongs_to]->(d);"
              println(query)
              try{
                      var con = DriverManager.getConnection(url_neo4j, neo4j_user, neo4j_password)
                          var stmt = con.createStatement()
                          var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)
                          con.close()
              }catch{
              case ex: SQLException =>{
                  println(ex.getMessage)
              }
              }
  } 

def operations(sqlContext: SQLContext){
    ....
    #Get 'data' before this step
    city_attributes = entity_metadata.filter(entity_metadata("source_name") === "tb_city").map(x =>x.getString(5)).collect()
    case_attributes = entity_metadata.filter(entity_metadata("source_name") === "tb_case_number").map(x =>x.getString(5)).collect()
    location_attributes = entity_metadata.filter(entity_metadata("source_name") === "tb_location").map(x =>x.getString(5)).collect()
    incident_attributes= entity_metadata.filter(entity_metadata("source_name") === "tb_incident").map(x =>x.getString(5)).collect()

    data.foreach(graphInsert)

}

object GraphObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {  
      val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("GraphNeo4j")
        .setMaster("xyz")
        .set("spark.cores.max","2")
        .set("spark.executor.memory","10g")

      Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
      Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
      val graph = new GraphInsert()
      graph.operations(sqlContext)

  }
}
```

Comment: Prepare data using Spark -> dump to csv -> bulk import?

Comment: This test is supposed to be big data scalable. Right now i have 50k records. But its supposed to have in millions. I always thought one csv file with such huge chunk of data will not be an optimal big data solution. Any suggestions on that? take example if i will merge city case, location and incident with each having 10 GB info and assuming they all have similar size. denormalized/processed info will have close to 40GB info.

Comment: With that being said. I can definately map and reduce it to multiple csv files and upload. But any comments on improving the job without dumping to disk?

Comment: Yeah many comments first of all you are collecting data multiple times ! That are lot of jobs just to insert data . Use the SPARK UI to optimize the code.

Do not collect data multiple times instead of collect use map and compose your data using map and flatMap and then inside that call the GraphinsertFunction

That would optimize your code upto a lot of extent !
After that still you want to optimize extract the get connection from that function and open it for first time and then close it using the time delay.

Comment: I am collecting the metadata in 4 places for some other reason. It just helps to construct the query. There are not more than 10 records there. Its basically just fetching the column list. So removing collect wont help much. Huge data is in 'data' dataframe and graphInsert runs multiple times. And your comment helps a lot i will initialize opening and closing connection one time.  You probably answered my issue 1. Any comments on issue no. 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you write inside the closure i.e it needs to be executed on Worker gets distributed. 
You can read more about it here : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka

And as you increase the number of cores, I think it must not effect the application because if you do not specify it ! then it takes the greedy approach ! I hope this document helps .

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what is happening but i am not doing any counters or accumulators. All i care about is query being executed on neo4j. Any Idea how i should prevent the duplicates nodes being created if i have to restructure my approach?

Comment: .set("spark.cores.max","2")  is what that creates duplicate nodes. If its set to 1 then job runs perfectly fine.

Comment: understand the closure and what is running on the driver and what is running on the Worker. Then you will get the whole notion !

Answer (score 0):

I am done improving the process but nothing could make it as fast as LOAD command in Cypher.
Hope this helps someone though:
use `foreachPartition` instead of `foreach` gives significant gain while doing such process. Also adding periodic commit using cypher.